# Package System is broken - I need to fix... can't add or remove apps

Tags: package-management, system, gimp

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and it was working fine.  Installed Gimp 2.6 and it was working fine.  Then installed Gimp 2.8 beta and it broke my package catalog. I cannot remove Gimp nor anything else and cannot add any new updates because it is broken. Any default repair available to me during boot up or using the software manager does not work.  Here is my error message...

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5% 
(Reading database ... 10% 
(Reading database ... 15% 
(Reading database ... 20% 
(Reading database ... 25% 
(Reading database ... 30% 
(Reading database ... 35% 
(Reading database ... 40% 
(Reading database ... 45% 
(Reading database ... 50% 
(Reading database ... 55% 
(Reading database ... 60% 
(Reading database ... 65% 
(Reading database ... 70% 
(Reading database ... 75% 
(Reading database ... 80% 
(Reading database ... 85% 
(Reading database ... 90% 
(Reading database ... 95% 
(Reading database ... 100% 
(Reading database ... 180355 files and directories currently installed.) 
Preparing to replace gimp 2.6.12-1ubuntu1 (using .../gimp_2.8.0~rc1-0precise0~ppa_i386.deb) ... 
Unpacking replacement gimp ... 
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/gimp_2.8.0~rc1-0precise0~ppa_i386.deb (--unpack): 
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/file-xmc', which is also in package gimp-plugin-registry 3.5.4-1 
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already 
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe) 
Processing triggers for man-db ... 
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ... 
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ... 
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index... 
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ... 
Errors were encountered while processing: 
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gimp_2.8.0~rc1-0precise0~ppa_i386.deb
```

This is another error when trying to use the Software Manager repair option...

```
The Package System is Broken...

Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.  Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f

Apps cannot be added or removed until the Package Catalog is repaired.
```

Any help will be much appreciated as I do not want to reinstall Ubuntu 12.04, it was a long process.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1):

Dan,

I had Package Catalog error. My problem was similar but not the same as yours, package error, typo error in terminal causing typo error in PPA, ending in update manager and ubuntu software center could not be operated. Asked to report, but no way out to fix.

Then I found this link and finally succeeded to repair the damage. Now update manager and software center is up and running again:

http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/fix-duplicate-sources-list-entry-errors-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/

Basically we learned there to use terminal, sudo, which is powerful; how to list and edit damaged or erroneous text.

In my case, the whole problem was caused by typo error in PPA. So with the guidance of above website, I was able in terminal to locate the erroneous text in PPA (since the Update Manager at least told me, which line which address was wrong. Opened up gedit and delete it. Than it was fixed. I was trying hud.

In your case, it is more complicated. Since new gimp may have done more damage. You may have to remove PPA in Update Manger Setting. Read carefully from any error report from your system, then locate and edit it if possible.

Until there is a better help, I hope my answer can help you.

Good luck.

Toni